# Can I trust 3rd party software?

Tags: security

I've begun to appreciate Ubuntu and the philosophy of open source software, and now I have a doubt about 3rd party software. Is it a bad idea to download them or can I trust every open source software? Will they affect the stability of my OS (Ubuntu) or cause some security errors?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to stay away from downloading and installing software from unknown sources, because you'll put your system at risk (security). Stick to the Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic for downloading and installing software.